# How to open files in new window?

Tags: nautilus, sublime-text-2

I know that there's an OSX-only setting for that:

```
"open_files_in_new_window": true
```

But how do I achieve that in Linux?

Comment: What linux version are you talking about ?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 beta and Mint 12, both running Nautilus as file manager

Comment: You can start sublime with `-n` or `--new-window`. See `subl --help` for more.